# Everything is pixelated in python tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

In tkinter the circles and lines I make look really rough and pixelated.

For example these are my circles in tkinter:
[image]

I would like them to look more smooth like this:
[image]

P.S. Sorry if it is a stupid or obvious question but I did not see something similar asked.

P.P.S sorry for my bad english

Comment: When you scale down a large image, that "compression" leads to losing some detail. Essentially, you're trying to fit a very large amount of pixels into a very small area. By necessity, you can't fit all those pixels into such a small area.

Comment: The feature you're looking for is called anti-aliasing, and it's up to the software you're using if it's available or turned on by default.

Comment: (to Michael) That is not really what i meant. If you look at the two pictures above, you can see, that in tkinter 5 drawn circles are all made of squares (pixels), and it easy to see them, but not on the picture from google. By zooming i meant, that even very small text in google will still looks nice and smooth, but similar text in tkinter will be made out of pixels that you can literally count

Comment: Thanks Mark. So this is something like in paint, if you have two side by side colors, in order to remove that edge you blur it by mixing them, so the are smooth transition between them. And text l see in google is not just black, but the nearest pixels to text are mixed, so like pixel gradient from black to white for example happens, right?

Comment: Exactly right.  Anti-aliasing creates the *illusion* of smoother shapes by doing a mix for adjacent pixels.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As commenters have noted, what you are looking for is called *anti-aliasing*.

To the best of my knowledge, `tkinter` (and the underlying `tk` toolkit) does not support it.
While techniques for anti-aliasing are actually older than `tk`, the display hardware for PCs back in the day generally did not support it when `tk` was started, and most computers where not powerful enough to do it in software. I'm not even sure it anti-aliasing is natively available now in all the platforms that `tk` runs on.

There is however a kind ot *poor man's anti-aliasing* that you can do to, as outlined in this [bCNC issue](https://github.com/vlachoudis/bCNC/issues/986).

It is suited to draw on a single-color background.
What it comes down to is to draw a line 0.5 pixel wider with a color intensity of 1/3 of the intended line and then draw the intended line over it.

Another option might be to use a special canvas backed by the [*anti-grain geometry* library](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anti-Grain_Geometry) called `FigureCanvasTkAgg`; this is part of matplotlib.
But so far I have not found a good example of using it without a matplotlib `Figure`. And to use it you need to install `matplotlib` with the `anti-grain geometry` backend and all its dependencies for your operating system.